# What's the fundamental difference between the MIT and the Boost Open Source licenses?

Tags: licensing, mit-license

What's the fundamental difference between the [MIT open source licence](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) :

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
>   CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
>   TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

and the [Boost Open Source license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsl1.0) :

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person or
>   organization obtaining a copy of the software and accompanying
>   documentation covered by this license (the "Software") to use,
>   reproduce, display, distribute, execute, and transmit the Software,
>   and to prepare derivative works of the Software, and to permit
>   third-parties to whom the Software is furnished to do so, all subject
>   to the following:
>
> The copyright notices in the Software and this entire statement,
>   including the above license grant, this restriction and the following
>   disclaimer, must be included in all copies of the Software, in whole
>   or in part, and all derivative works of the Software, unless such
>   copies or derivative works are solely in the form of
>   machine-executable object code generated by a source language
>   processor.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, TITLE AND
>   NON-INFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS OR ANYONE
>   DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE BE LIABLE FOR ANY DAMAGES OR OTHER
>   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT
>   OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
>   THE SOFTWARE.

I'm willing to take an exception to the "retain this copyright notice" bit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This [Ticket Regarding the Boost Open Source License v1.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20150106221458/http://ideas.opensource.org/ticket/45) lists 4 different things that make this license different than the MIT license.

Two of them have to do with warranties.  If you use a BSL licensed library, you'll need to write your own disclaimer stating that you aren't responsible if the software turns into a three-headed monster and does some bad stuff to your customers.  The warranty disclaimer isn't extended to licensees.  The advantage is that you can also apply your own warranty for a fee if you'd like, should you want to provide one.

One of them has to do with the copyright notice.  You are right that it doesn't need to be included in binaries.

The last one makes it clear that licenses can be issued to either individuals or organizations.

Comment: I don't understand how the Boost Software Licensed library allows one to write their own disclaimer. The Boost Software License clearly mentions in its second paragraph that retaining the disclaimer of warranty is mandatory in all copies. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/251796/144709 for my question about this.